# Twitter @anywhere login implementation

Tags: authentication, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I'm new to Twitter @anywhere. Is @anywhere login feature is intended to integrate our website with Twitter login? just like Facebook connect? 
If yes, What is the callback url used for and what callback url should be provided?

I've tried to add this @anywhere login feature to my site and I'm testing it from a localhost / 127.0.0.1 site. I use the following code

```javascript
twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
  T("#twitter-login").connectButton({
    authComplete: function(user) {

      //triggered when auth completed successfully
      alert('test login complete');

      currentUser = T.currentUser;

      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
      userInfo.innerHTML =

      '<img src="' + currentUser.data('profile_image_url') + '"/>'
      + currentUser.data('screen_name');
    }
  });
});
```

If I don't provide any callback url, after authorizing the user, Twitter give a

```
Sorry, something went wrong.
The provided callback url http://localhost:9000/ is not authorized for the client   registered to 'http://127.0.0.1:9000'.
```

So then I provide a custom callback url with the following code

```
twttr.anywhere.config({ callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:9000"});
```

After adding that code, no error occurred but I ended up having two tabs opened of the same page. One is the page I use to login and the other one is the callback url page. And also the code inside the ***"authComplete:"*** section is not run, the alert is not shown.

Did I do anything wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twitter @Anywhere users domains to authenticate the callback url.

For twitter server, `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are two differente things. As your are using `localhost` as your callback url, try adding this domain on the authorized domains configuration on your app configuration att dev.twitter.com